# Using fadeToggle + fade all other when having set of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, fade

I have set of divs inside one container div called: **"people"**.
each div is called **"people-box"**
inside each **"people-box"** I have a div called: **"people-description"**

So this will describe my hierarchy:

```
<div class="people">

  <div class="people-box">
    <div class="people-description"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="people-box">
    <div class="people-description"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="people-box">
    <div class="people-description"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I would like to trigger to actions here:
when someone is clicking on "people-box" div I want to fade toggle the description, simply show and hide

it is working using this method:

```
$('.people-box').click(function(){
        $(this).find('.people-description').fadeToggle(500);

});
```

however, this is working only when I am on the same div clicking to show the description and clicking again to hide it.
if the description is shown and I am clicking on another **"people-box"** it is not fading the one that is shown..
I would like that too work (toggling the description clicking the same div)
but also when moving to another **"people-box"** I would like to fade out all others that left open

Will appreciate any solution
Thanks

Comment: You can hide all description by doing `$('.people-description').fadeOut()` then you just need to fade in the current clicked one which you already have the code for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fade out all description by doing

```
$('.people-description').fadeOut(500);
```

all together

```
$('.people-box').click(function(){
    var $el = $(this).find('.people-description');
    $('.people-description').not($el).fadeOut()
    $el.fadeToggle(500);
});
```

The 500 milliseconds is optional, change it if you need to

http://jsfiddle.net/65w90pqj/1/

Update:

```
$('.people-box').click(function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass('people-description')) {
        var $el = $(this).find('.people-description');
        $('.people-description').not($el).fadeOut()
        $el.fadeToggle(500);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/65w90pqj/2/

Comment: That will cause the one you click on to fade twice. You might want to do something like `$('.people-box').not(this).find('.people-description').fadeOut(500);` instead

Comment: Working beautifully @Huangism!  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @Huangism  one quick question: it works perfectly, however, when the "people-description" is open there is text there and email. when I click on it it fades out, anyway to get this funstion wirking the way it is except when I hover or click on the open "people-description" box?  Thanks

Comment: @gilhamer there is a way to prevent that but without seeing how your html is structured, it's hard to say how to code it. Ask another question with your current markup and js. It shouldn't be long until someone answers

Comment: Hi @Huangism I have a real link if it makes it easier - http://bit.ly/1ybwo6q kindly, click on one of the people there and try to select the text or send email by clicking on the email and see what happens. if you can help it would be great. Thanks

Comment: @gilhamer I have made an update to my answer to not trigger the fade for the description

Comment: Thanks @Huangism  your code is working perfectly in Jsfiddle, I have no idea why it is not working on my site.. :( same code. you can view the source in my link http://bit.ly/1ybwo6q. I will try to see what I did wrong and why clicking on my description box always fades it out..

Comment: @gilhamer ok you have to do something different since you have other elements in there. You have to do `if (!$(e.target).closest('.people-description').length) {` see http://jsfiddle.net/65w90pqj/3/

Comment: Working amazingly! I really appreciate your effort! thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly,

```
$('.people-box').click(function () {
  $this = $(this).find('.people-description');
  $('.people-description').not($this).fadeOut(500);
  $this.fadeToggle(500);
})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmj34mv9/1/)

Comment: Thanks @T J  your answer is also working! just the code at the bottom is a little bit more what I needed. Thanks a lot!